# Simply Bendy in Blendy

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

Just curious, I couldn't find any answers to my specific question, then again perhaps I don't have the right words to ask it in the first place. I was in the middle of doing a low poly object when generally I'd be sculpting and I realized every little move that I make, I have to add to or adjust curvatures in each cut on the poly. I was curious if there was a way to select whole sections and any manipulation would automatically adjust each one, things such as a simple rotation if instead of everything flatly moving with the rotation, if each cut on the poly would rotate at the same time the same direction.

Comment: There's a pose brush that projects a bone with automatic weight and tries to attempt what you're saying, I think.